# How to solve MultiValueDictKeyError 'icon'?

Tags: python, django

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import Product
from django.utils import timezone

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'products/home.html')

@login_required
def create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST['title'] and request.POST['body'] and request.POST['url'] and request.POST['icon'] and request.POST['image']:
            product = Product()
            product.title = request.POST['title']
            product.body = request.POST['body']
            product.url = request.POST['url']
            product.icon = request.FILES['icon']
            product.image = request.FILES['image']
            product.pub_date = timezone.datetime.now()
            product.hunter = request.user
            product.save()
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            return render(request, 'products/create.html', {'error':'all info is required'})
    else:
        return render(request, 'products/create.html')
```

Comment: Please format your code and write a proper description of your problem!

Comment: show your traceback

Comment: Apparently your `icon` and `image` are in `request.POST` (based on the `if` condition...

Comment: Instead of `request.POST['title']` use get method for getting item as -  `request.POST.get('title')` and  please write your problem in proper manner

Comment: @KlausD. your feedback is correct, but is not very detailed. It is a good idea to ask authors to read [ask] and [mcve], so they know how they can improve.

Comment: @PankajSharma, regarding the "proper manner" of writing questions, your feedback does not contain any guidance about what that manner is. Consider pointing question authors to the Stack Overflow help centre and let them know _in what way_ their question can improve.

Answer (score 0):

Lol guys i solved my problem because

request.POST['icon'] and request.POST['image']

that request is post and i try to upload files in database

request.FILES['icon'] and request.FILES['image']

this is correct

thanks for your reply guys